# how to create class static variable from outside class python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create a static class variable from outside of the class or want to access variable declared from the outer class.

```
class test(object):
    in_class = var

class test():
global var
var = 20
j = test()
print j.in_class
```

This gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class test(object):
  File "class_test.py", line 2, in test
    in_class = var
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

Comment: Try declaring and setting `var` before class declerarion

Comment: thanks it's worked